# UICollectionView with custom flow layout - cells glitching when scrolling while having an active pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

so I'm building my own Drag&Drop system. For that to work, I need a way to create "gaps" between cells in `collectionViews`, where the user hovers dragged items.

I'm trying out stuff right now and got a basic demo working using a custom flow layout that moves the cells around.

The demo I did consists of a simple `collectionView`(using `IGListKit` but that doesn't matter for this problem, I'm pretty sure) and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that allows you to pan over the collectionView to create a gap beneath your finger.

I achieve this by invalidating the layout every time the `pan gesture reconizer` changes. It's working that way, but when I simultaneously scroll while panning over the `collectionView`, the cells seem to glitch a little bit. It looks like this (it looks as if the rendering of the cells can't keep up):

[image]

I'm pretty sure the problem is within the `makeAGap`function that contains this call:

```
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

If I don't animate the invalidation, like this

```
self.invalidateLayout()
self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The glitch does not appear at all. It has something to do with the animation. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

PS: Here's the code (there's more `IGListKit` stuff but that's not important):

```
class MyCustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 6

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 300
    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0

    var gap: IndexPath? = nil
    var gapPosition: CGPoint? = nil

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // cache contains the cached layout attributes
        guard cache.isEmpty, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        // I'm using IGListKit, so every cell is in its own section in my case
        for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)
            // If a gap has been set, just make the current offset (contentWidth) bigger to
            // simulate a "missing" item, which creates a gap
            if let gapPosition = self.gapPosition {
                if gapPosition.x >= (contentWidth - 100) && gapPosition.x < (contentWidth + 100) {
                    contentWidth += 100
                }
            }

            // contentWidth is used as x origin
            let frame = CGRect(x: contentWidth, y: 10, width: 100, height: contentHeight)
            contentWidth += frame.width + cellPadding

            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = frame
            cache.append(attributes)
        }
    }

    public func makeAGap(at indexPath: IndexPath, position: CGPoint) {
        gap = indexPath
        self.cache = []
        self.contentWidth = 0
        self.gapPosition = position


        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

        //invalidateLayout() // Using this, the glitch does NOT appear
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    /// IGListKit stuff: Data for self.collectionView ("its cells", which represent the rows)
    public var data: [String] {
        return (0...100).compactMap { "\($0)" }
    }

    /// This collectionView will consist of cells, that each have their own collectionView.
    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = MyCustomLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xeeeeee)

        adapter.collectionView = collectionView
        adapter.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 1000, height: 300)

        return collectionView
    }()

    /// IGListKit stuff. Data manager for the collectionView
    private lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
        let adapter = ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
        return adapter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = collectionView

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(pan:)))
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        pan.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc private func handlePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: pan.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            return
        }

        (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MyCustomLayout)?.makeAGap(at: indexPath, position: pan.location(in: collectionView))
    }
}

extension ViewController: ListAdapterDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
        return data as [ListDiffable]
    }

    func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
        return RowListSection()
    }

    func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this keeps happening. I spend hours and hours trying to fix a problem, give up to ask a question here and minutes later I find the/a solution.

So, I can't entirely explain why this glitch is occurring, but it seems like it's got to do with the drawing of the screen. 
I added a `CADisplayLink`to synchronize the layout invalidation with the refresh rate of the screen and now the glitch is gone (code snippet below for anyone interested).

**However, I would love to know what exactly is happening there and why synchronizing the invalidation fixes the drawing glitch.** I'm gonna look into it as well but I'm not that experienced so if anyone knows about stuff like this, *I'd highly appreciate a new (more detailed) answer to this question :)*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = collectionView

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(pan:)))
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        pan.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))
        displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? = nil
    var position: CGPoint? = nil

    @objc private func update() {
        if let indexPath = self.indexPath, let position = self.position {
            (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MyCustomLayout)?.makeAGap(at: indexPath, position: position)
        }
    }

    @objc private func handlePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: pan.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            return
        }

        // buffer the values
        self.indexPath = indexPath
        position = pan.location(in: collectionView)
}
```